# Normalization of curve and integral cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, curves, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a 2-dimensional complex manifold, $C\subset X$ be a compact, reduced irreducible divisor.
let $\nu: \tilde{C}\to C$ be a normalization(In this situation,$\tilde{C}$ is a riemann surface.).How to show that$H^2(C,\mathbb{Z})\cong H^2(\tilde{C},\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Show that $H^2(C, \mathbb{Z})=H^2_c(C, \mathbb{Z}) \simeq H^2_c(C^{\text{sm}}, \mathbb{Z}) \simeq H^2_c(\tilde{C}, \mathbb{Z}) = H^2(\tilde{C}, \mathbb{Z})$ using the long exact sequence in compactly supported cohomology associated to $C^{\text{sm}} \subset C$ and $C^{\text{sm}} \subset \tilde {C}$. Here I write $C^{\text{sm}}$ for the smooth locus of $C$, which is naturally an open subset of both $C$ and $\tilde{C}$.

Comment: @user45878 I understand. Thank you!